# CSS counters for headings in divs resetting too often

Tags: css, css-counter

I've copy-pasted what seems to be some popular code for automatically numbering headers in HTML (from [here](https://philarcher.org/diary/2013/headingnumbers/))

But this seems to fail if my headings are inside divs:

### example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        article {counter-reset: h2}
        h2 {counter-reset: h3}
        h3 {counter-reset: h4}
        h4 {counter-reset: h5}
        h5 {counter-reset: h6}

        h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h2) ". "; }
        h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "; }
        h4:before {counter-increment: h4; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "; }
        h5:before {counter-increment: h5; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "; }
        h6:before {counter-increment: h6; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) "." counter(h6) ". "; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="Layout">
            <div class="Layout-main">
                <article class="post h-entry" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <div class="post-content e-content" itemprop="articleBody">
                        <div class="container" id="notebook-container">
                            <div><div><div><h2 id="Background">Background </h2></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="Enzyme-Kinetics">Enzyme Kinetics </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="Parameter-Inference">Parameter Inference </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="The-Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane-Approximation">The Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane Approximation </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h2 id="Exploring-the-Forward-Model">Exploring the Forward Model </h2></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="A-Standard-Example">A Standard Example </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="Breaking-the-Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane-Assumptions:-Initial-Substrate:Enzyme-Ratio">Breaking the Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane Assumptions: Initial Substrate:Enzyme Ratio </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="Breaking-the-Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane-Assumptions:-Fast-Enzyme-Substrate-Complex-Kinetics">Breaking the Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane Assumptions: Fast Enzyme-Substrate Complex Kinetics </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h3 id="Comparing-Integrators">Comparing Integrators </h3></div></div></div>
                            <div><div><div><h2 id="Inference">Inference </h2></div></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

It's especially curious to me this works for the h2 but not the h3's...

Comment: Add the HTML with the CSS as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unexpected behavior is caused by the deeply nested subheadings inside `.container`. According to the [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#scope):

> Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that resetting a counter in a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically creates a new instance of the counter. This is important for situations like lists in HTML, where elements can be nested inside themselves to arbitrary depth.

Your [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) implementation works as expected for the example when the `<h2>`-`<h6>` elements are adjacent siblings in the `.container`. After I removed all those extra `<div>` tags so the subheadings were adjacent siblings, the [`counter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter()) usage displays numbers for subheadings and increments them correctly.

You first define your counters (by resetting them) with [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset). Then you increment and insert them with [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) as generated content using the `:before` pseudo class. The counter works smoothly after the DOM structure was updated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        article {counter-reset: h2}
        h2 {counter-reset: h3}
        h3 {counter-reset: h4}
        h4 {counter-reset: h5}
        h5 {counter-reset: h6}

        h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h2) ". "; }
        h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "; }
        h4:before {counter-increment: h4; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "; }
        h5:before {counter-increment: h5; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "; }
        h6:before {counter-increment: h6; content: counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) "." counter(h6) ". "; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="Layout">
            <div class="Layout-main">
                <article class="post h-entry" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <div class="post-content e-content" itemprop="articleBody">
                        <div class="container" id="notebook-container">
                            <h2 id="Background">Background</h2>
                            <h3 id="Enzyme-Kinetics">Enzyme Kinetics </h3>
                            <h3 id="Parameter-Inference">Parameter Inference </h3>
                            <h3 id="The-Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane-Approximation">The Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane Approximation </h3>
                            <h2 id="Exploring-the-Forward-Model">Exploring the Forward Model </h2>
                            <h3 id="A-Standard-Example">A Standard Example </h3>
                            <h3 id="Breaking-the-Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane-Assumptions:-Initial-Substrate:Enzyme-Ratio">Breaking the Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane Assumptions: Initial Substrate:Enzyme Ratio </h3>
                            <h3 id="Breaking-the-Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane-Assumptions:-Fast-Enzyme-Substrate-Complex-Kinetics">Breaking the Michaelis-Menten/Briggs-Haldane Assumptions: Fast Enzyme-Substrate Complex Kinetics </h3>
                            <h3 id="Comparing-Integrators">Comparing Integrators </h3>
                            <h2 id="Inference">Inference </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```